# Radical equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can someone please explain how to to solve this question, through finding n

Question:
$$\frac 1 {n^2} + \frac 1 n = \frac 1 {2n^2}$$

I tried to simplify it down and I got stuck with this, and I don't know what to do next:

$$2n^2+3n^2=0$$

Comment: No roots, no radical equations.

Comment: Note $\dfrac 1{2n^2} = - \dfrac 1n$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

I assume $n\neq 0$ so work on this one instead: $$n^2\left(\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{2n^2}\right)$$

Comment: Might as well use $2n^2$ and eliminate all the fractions.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply both sides by $2n^2$:

> $$2+2n=1$$

Comment: This is a cool feature